# Character of or from the novel xy

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is the correct one:

> Paul is the main character **of/from** the novel XY.

I found both online but was told by a friend that only "from" works here.. which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

Both are entirely possible and can be used.  Which one is more "correct" depends on context.  More common than either of them is ["**in** the novel."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=character%20%2A%20the%20novel&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccharacter%20%2A%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcharacter%20in%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20of%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20and%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20from%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20to%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20throughout%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20within%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20is%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20that%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20which%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ccharacter%20*%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcharacter%20in%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20of%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20and%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20from%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20to%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20throughout%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20within%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20is%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20that%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcharacter%20which%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0)

As a native US English speaker, I would tend to say "Paul is the main character **of** the novel", but "Vronsky is a character **from/in** *Anna Karenina*."

Comment: So all thre options are correct in the following sentence?: Tom is the main character in/from/of the novel "Tom Sawyer. He is xy years old and...

Comment: With "main character" I would only tend to use *of* or *in*, [as Ngrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=main+character+%2A+the+novel&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmain%20character%20%2A%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmain%20character%20of%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmain%20character%20in%20the%20novel%3B%2Cc0).  It's hard for me to explain why "the main character" feels like it should take a different preposition from "a character".

Comment: Would you also only use of/in in this context:   The given excerpt deals with Paul, the main character ___ the novel.

Comment: Yes, in that case I think I would still say *of* or *in*.